# How can I forward a message back to MessageReceived when I've called context.Wait in a LuisDialog intent handler?

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding

I am building a small bot, which is working out nicely, but I am facing one flow issue that I just can't seem to get out of. I use a LuisDialog that interprets the user's message. Within a certain intent handler method, I display a carousel with a 'Unsubscribe' button in the panel, and call `context.Wait(Uitschrijven)` to handle the user's selection from the carousel.

This means that the next incoming message will hit this method:

```
private async Task Uitschrijven(IDialogContext context,IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result)
{
    ...
}
```

In this method, I'm expecting the user to have clicked a button from the carousel, which will send a message formatted something like `"id:3"`. Of course, the user can just type some other new message rather than continuing this flow. The problem is that if they do, I that next message is received by my 'Uitschrijven' method, where it won't be handled correctly. How can I send it back to be re-interpreted by the LuisDialog, so that the correct intent is matched?

Ideally I would like to forward the message again to my `MessageReceived` function from my LuisDialog.

However, the Forward() method expect a resumeafter method, which I don't need.
There's also EndConversation, but it just ends the conversation without interpreting.

Does anyone know how to ensure that these new messages will be processed by the `MessageReceived` method so the user is able to continue in this scenario?

Comment: Please post the code so we can understand better the flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding is that you're receiving the user's response in a method like `private async Task Uitschrijven(IDialogContext context,IAwaitable result)` which exists within your Luis dialog, and if the incoming message came from your button, you want to process it, but if the message is something else, you want it to go back to the MessageReceived method of the same dialog. If that's correct, you can simply do something like this:

```
private async Task Uitschrijven(IDialogContext context,IAwaitable result) 
{
    var message = await result;
    if( /* message matches what you're expecting from button */) 
    {
        // process message from button
    }
    else
    {
        // simply pass the IAwaitable to MessageReceived
        await MessageReceived(context, result);
    }
}
```

If I'm understanding the scenario correctly, this is likely better than the other suggestion of using a Scorable, since with a scorable, every single message would run through the Unsubscribe scorable, and this logic may be able to be triggered in places where it's not appropriate.

If you feel that that's not an accurate understanding of your requirements, please feel free to edit your question with more clarifying details!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The solutions from Sam fits my need the best. But I will use the Scorable for another scenario I am facing and this fits in perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

This may be a good use case for a [Scorable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-scorable-dialogs).  There will be some tradeoffs though.

Your user would just have to type "unsubscribe" at any point or click a button with the postback/imback value of "unsubscribe".  You can choose any text you desire as the recognized value.  This way your unsubscribe logic will run independent of any other logic and you will not get trapped in your flow as you are now.  Since the unsubscribe event will be handled by the global handler (Scorable)  you can just handle any other message sent by the user as you normally would, in your case in a LuisDialog.

If you do not want your user to be able to unsubscribe at any point this solution will probably not work for you.  In this case please post your code as @Ezequiel asked so we can better understand your flow.  This would not be the only way in which to handle your flow.

Here is some info to look over:
[Scorable Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hnU3lPHhv88)

[Scorable Blog](https://blog.tallan.com/2017/05/23/global-message-handling-and-catching-the-bot-framework-way/)

[Scorable Blog](http://www.garypretty.co.uk/2017/04/13/using-scorables-for-global-message-handling-and-interrupt-dialogs-in-bot-framework/)